# Find the maximum and minimum values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the maximum and minimum values of:
>   $$ 4 \sin x + \frac{9}{1+\sin x}$$ For $ 0 \le x \le \pi $.

What I have done:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = 4\cos x-\frac{9\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$$

After equating the above to $0$, I found that $ x=\pi/6 $.

I do not know what to do next to find the maximum and minimum values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The extreme values must occur at critical points or at endpoints of the interval. Calculate $f(\pi/6)$, $f(0)$, and $f(\pi)$, and compare the values.

Comment: Draw a picture first. The constraint $x \in [0,\pi]$ may be important, in which case you cannot just look for zeros of the derivative.

Comment: If not sure on such questions it can be very useful to sketch a graph.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - you are assuming the function is continuous, which should probably be mentioned given the form it takes (ie note that discontinuities are outside the interval)

Comment: @MarkBennet: I would venture that it is always fruitful to draw a picture for such problems.

Comment: @Mark: No, I **know** that the function is continuous. Were I giving an actual answer, I’d point out that this also needs to be checked, but I’m not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - didn't mean to be rude: I think it is the word "must" which evoked continuity for me, since it instinctively references a theorem for which continuity is essential, and I could see a similar problem being given in an exam with a discontinuous function to handle.

Comment: @Mark: Not to worry: I was actually more amused than annoyed. This might have been better conveyed by ‘No, I **know** that the function is continuous, and I’m **assuming** (possibly incorrectly) that the OP will check this’!

Comment: What kind of Differential Equation this is, as what the tag indicates!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$ work as well.  You can then use [The Extreme Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem).  You merely plug in the critical values and the endpoints.  The largest is the max, the smallest the min.

Answer (score 1):

With apologies to Magritte, this is not an answer, but doesn't fit in the comments.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the replies and yes I should have drawn a graph.
But is there any method to work out the minimum and maximum values without the use of a graph?

Comment: See Brian's comment above. Either the constraints are relevant or not at a solution. If not, using the derivative can characterize a solution, but if a constraint is active, care must be taken. A trivial example is to maximize $x^3$ subject to $|x|=1$. Clearly the solution is $x=1$, but the derivative is of no help here.

Comment: You remind me of my all-time favorite Usenet sig; see the bottom of [this post](http://www.andes.missouri.edu/Personal/DMartinez/Diffusion/msg00390.html).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

Simply substitute $ x=\pi/6 $ ( you have correctly discarded the other root) into

$$ 4 \sin x + \frac{9}{1+\sin x} $$

Use second derivative test to find out that it is minimum.